# How to use find_first_not_of with a vector of string?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stl-algorithm

Let's say I have the following object:

```
vector<string> data = {"12","12","12","12","13","14","15", "15", "15", "15", "18"};
```

I'm trying to find the first non-repeating entry in the data object.
For example, data.find_first_not_of(data.at(0)); this would work if data is of string type only (no container).

How can I achieve the same thing with an object of type vector.

I looked at adjacent_find and find_if_not from the algorithm library, but to no avail.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: is the data always sorted?

Comment: Do you just want `vector<string>` as in your title, or arbitrary `vector<T>`, or `vector<vector<T>>`, or something else? It's not really clear from your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, not! I can't mess with the order of the elements, it has to be as it is.

Comment: @Useless Just a vector<string>.

Comment: So you claimed to have something that works for `vector<string>`. I think there's a mistake there anyway, but if you say it works, what's the question?

Comment: from your `data`, are "13", "14" and "18" the only non-repeating entries? And "13" is the first?

Comment: @Useless Sorry for the confusion, I meant that it works only with string and not with vector<string>.

Comment: @Caleth it doesn't have to be, the data set is huge. This is just an example.

Comment: so you want something like `string find_first_nonrepeated(vector<string>&)` ?

Comment: In the example you gave, what should the answer be?

Comment: You could use an auxiliary container, such as a `std::set` or `std::map` to check for duplicate entries.

Comment: @Xigma -- *it doesn't have to be, the data set is huge* -- How big is "huge"?

Comment: I'm not sure you realise what [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) does, or what it is intended for. It takes a set of characters and searches the string for the first character not in that set. Unless that is what you want, in which case [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) might be useful to you

Comment: @Caleth thank you for bringing the set_difference function to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What problem did you have with `adjacent_find`?  You should be able to use that with an inverse predicate:

```
std::vector<std::string> data = {"12","12","12","12","13","14","15", "15", "15", "15", "18"};

// Sort data here if necessary

auto itr = std::adjacent_find(data.cbegin(), data.cend(), std::not_equal_to<std::string>{});
if (itr != data.cend()) {
    std::cout << "First mismatch: " << *itr << " " << *std::next(itr) << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "All elements equal" << std::endl;
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U3kg0zzHoOpGGF4v)

Comment: This matches what OP _did_, but not what they claimed to want.

Comment: I wasn't using not_equal_to as a predicate. The one I had works only for two entries. The example reports "all elements equal" for this test sample "00", "00", "00", "11". It is not checking the last element, any idea why?

Comment: @Xigma Works fine for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/pYt127SGWU9vH9Qe

Comment: I see! It was actually the fault of my code that populates the data object. It wasn't taking the last element. Thank you for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to go through the list at least once, and you don't know when or where you will encounter the duplicate of a number (if there is one), one way to solve this is to first gather "statistics" and then from what you've gathered you can determine the first non-duplicate.

Here is an example using `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// struct to hold some information on the numbers
struct info
{
    std::string number;
    int count;
    int position;
    info(const std::string n, int c, int p) : number(n), count(c), position(p) {}
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> data = {"12","12","12","12","13","14","15", "15", "15", "15", "18"};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, info> infoMap;
    std::vector<info> vInfo;
    int pos = 0;

    // loop for each data element
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](const std::string& n) 
    { 
        // insert entry into the map
        auto pr = infoMap.insert(std::make_pair(n, info(n, 0, pos)));    

        // bump up the count for this entry.
        ++pr.first->second.count;

        // bump up the postion number
        ++pos;

    });

    // create a vector of the information with a count of 1 item.
    std::for_each(infoMap.begin(), infoMap.end(), [&](std::unordered_map<std::string, info>::value_type& vt) { if (vt.second.count == 1) vInfo.push_back(vt.second); });

    // sort this by position
    std::sort(vInfo.begin(), vInfo.end(), [&](const info& pr1, const info &pr2){return pr1.position < pr2.position; });

   // output the results
    if ( vInfo.empty() )
        std::cout << "All values are duplicated\n";
    else  
        std::cout << "The first number that isn't repeated is " << vInfo.front().number << "\n";
    }
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee8ea90cbcf806ea)

First, we just simply go through all the entries in the vector and just tally up the count for each item.  In addition, we store the position in the original list of where the item was found.

After that we filter out the ones with a count of exactly 1 and copy them to a vector.  We then sort this vector based on the position they were found in the original list.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. But, I believe it is an overkill for what I want to achieve.